# javascript to check if a field has a value

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

If it does not have a value do one thing, else do something else. See my code below. This is currently not working. I'm pretty sure my if statement is incorrect but unsure how to fix

```
if(new_steponecontractrecieved)
{
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_totalamountcollected").setValue(item2);
} else
{
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_totalamountcollected").setValue(item1+item2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```
var new_steponecontractrecieved= Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_steponecontractrecieved");
if(new_steponecontractrecieved!=null && new_steponecontractrecieved.getValue()!=null)
{
   //have a value do one thing
}
else if(new_steponecontractrecieved!=null)
{
  //does not have a value do other thing
}
```